# sqlite won't use index for query

Tags: sqlite, indexing

I'm using this query on my database

```
SELECT
      DISTINCT wb_expr_pattern2gene.gene
    FROM
      wb_expr_pattern2gene
    , wb_expr_pattern2anatomy_term
    , wb_anatomy_term2ancestor
    , wb_anatomy_term2cell
    WHERE
        wb_anatomy_term2cell.cell = 'P0'
    AND (
           wb_anatomy_term2cell.anatomy_term = wb_expr_pattern2anatomy_term.anatomy_term
        OR (
                wb_anatomy_term2cell.anatomy_term = wb_anatomy_term2ancestor.anatomy_term
            AND wb_anatomy_term2ancestor.ancestor_term = wb_expr_pattern2anatomy_term.anatomy_term
           )
        )
    AND wb_expr_pattern2anatomy_term.expr_pattern = wb_expr_pattern2gene.expr_pattern
;
```

which takes very long.
The reason is that sqlite won't use indices on the `wb_anatomy_term2ancestor` table

```
0|0|3|SEARCH TABLE wb_anatomy_term2cell USING INDEX wb_anatomy_term2cell__cell (cell=?) (~10 rows)
0|1|2|SCAN TABLE wb_anatomy_term2ancestor (~1000000 rows)
0|2|1|SEARCH TABLE wb_expr_pattern2anatomy_term USING INDEX wb_expr_pattern2anatomy_term__anatomy_term (anatomy_term=?) (~10 rows)
0|2|1|SEARCH TABLE wb_expr_pattern2anatomy_term USING INDEX wb_expr_pattern2anatomy_term__anatomy_term (anatomy_term=?) (~10 rows)
0|3|0|SEARCH TABLE wb_expr_pattern2gene USING INDEX wb_expr_pattern2gene__expr_pattern (expr_pattern=?) (~10 rows)
0|0|0|USE TEMP B-TREE FOR DISTINCT
```

although they exist

```
CREATE INDEX wb_anatomy_term2ancestor__anatomy_term__ancestor_term ON wb_anatomy_term2ancestor(anatomy_term, ancestor_term);
CREATE INDEX wb_anatomy_term2ancestor__anatomy_term ON wb_anatomy_term2ancestor(anatomy_term);
CREATE INDEX wb_anatomy_term2ancestor__ancestor_term ON wb_anatomy_term2ancestor(ancestor_term);
```

does sqlite have a good reason for this behaviour?

Comment: Your second index is redundant. It doesn't do anything your first index doesn't do. You're paying the cost of updating it for no benefit.

Comment: Please show the database schema.

Comment: @David Schwartz, do you mean wb_anatomy_term2ancestor__anatomy_term is included in wb_anatomy_term2ancestor__anatomy_term__ancestor_term?

Comment: @manuels: Any index that satisfies the rules for wb_anatomy_term2ancestor__anatomy_term__ancestor_term also satisfies the rules for wb_anatomy_term2ancestor__anatomy_term. So there is no point in having both. The second one adds nothing you don't already have in the first one, but it does add the cost of maintaining an additional index.

Answer (score 0):

This query is fast (but why?)

```
EXPLAIN QUERY PLAN SELECT
      wb_expr_pattern2gene.gene
    FROM
        wb_expr_pattern2gene
      , wb_expr_pattern2anatomy_term
    WHERE
    ((   
        wb_expr_pattern2anatomy_term.anatomy_term IN ( SELECT
          wb_anatomy_term2cell.anatomy_term
        FROM
          wb_anatomy_term2cell
        WHERE 
                wb_anatomy_term2cell.cell = 'P0'
        )
    )
    OR wb_expr_pattern2anatomy_term.anatomy_term IN ( SELECT
          wb_anatomy_term2ancestor.ancestor_term
        FROM
            wb_anatomy_term2ancestor
          , wb_anatomy_term2cell
        WHERE 
                wb_anatomy_term2cell.cell = 'P0'
            AND wb_anatomy_term2ancestor.anatomy_term = wb_anatomy_term2cell.anatomy_term
            AND wb_anatomy_term2cell.anatomy_term = wb_anatomy_term2ancestor.anatomy_term
       )
    )
    AND wb_expr_pattern2anatomy_term.expr_pattern = wb_expr_pattern2gene.expr_pattern
;

0|0|0|EXECUTE LIST SUBQUERY 1
1|0|0|SEARCH TABLE wb_anatomy_term2cell USING INDEX wb_anatomy_term2cell__cell (cell=?) (~10 rows)
0|0|1|SEARCH TABLE wb_expr_pattern2anatomy_term USING INDEX wb_expr_pattern2anatomy_term__anatomy_term (anatomy_term=?) (~250 rows)
0|0|0|EXECUTE LIST SUBQUERY 2
2|0|1|SEARCH TABLE wb_anatomy_term2cell USING INDEX wb_anatomy_term2cell__cell (cell=?) (~10 rows)
2|1|0|SEARCH TABLE wb_anatomy_term2ancestor USING COVERING INDEX wb_anatomy_term2ancestor__anatomy_term__ancestor_term (anatomy_term=?) (~2 rows)
0|0|1|SEARCH TABLE wb_expr_pattern2anatomy_term USING INDEX wb_expr_pattern2anatomy_term__anatomy_term (anatomy_term=?) (~250 rows)
0|0|0|EXECUTE LIST SUBQUERY 3
3|0|0|SEARCH TABLE wb_anatomy_term2cell USING INDEX wb_anatomy_term2cell__cell (cell=?) (~10 rows)
0|0|0|EXECUTE LIST SUBQUERY 4
4|0|1|SEARCH TABLE wb_anatomy_term2cell USING INDEX wb_anatomy_term2cell__cell (cell=?) (~10 rows)
4|1|0|SEARCH TABLE wb_anatomy_term2ancestor USING COVERING INDEX wb_anatomy_term2ancestor__anatomy_term__ancestor_term (anatomy_term=?) (~2 rows)
0|1|0|SEARCH TABLE wb_expr_pattern2gene USING INDEX wb_expr_pattern2gene__expr_pattern (expr_pattern=?) (~10 rows)
```